# What is wrong when I get a "Unable to determine code source archive"

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project that creates an executable JAR. Every now and then after a `mvn clean install` I get the following exception when I run the jar:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine code source archive
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getProperty(PropertiesLauncher.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getProperty(PropertiesLauncher.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getArgs(PropertiesLauncher.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:556)
... 6 more
```

Google only gets me 4 hits of the sourcefile itself. And ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some errors during maven packaging phase and the resulting executable jar file will be erroneous.

Do the following:

1. Always read maven log output when building and packaging
2. Fix the packaging phase
3. Include an assembly descriptor in order to assemble a bin-tar
4. Include the spring boot jar